# Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference (showing form) in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, forms

*Screenshot:*
[image: Questionable error]

I use Visual Basic 2008 for this one. I have a menustrip where I could click on a menu and show the form. Now, I typed the simple `BrandListing.show` where "BrandListing" is a form, and as you can see, the code is in the menu's click property.

What should I do? Isn't this the way to make forms appear? Why does this error happen?

Comment: `Dim form As New BrandListing` then
`form.Show`. In it's simplest terms.

Comment: Form classes do not show up in the "Data Sources" window.  So surely it is a DataSet class.  Using the type name instead of an object variable only works on Form classes, a VB6 compat hack.  You get the "requires an object" error before you get the "doesn't have a Show method" error.

Answer (score 0):

Is `BrandListing` your form? If so;

```
    Dim f As New BrandListing(Your_Parameters)
    f.MdiParent = Me 'Optional, only if you want the form to be a child form
    f.Show()
```

Answer (score 0):

> You have referenced a non-shared member within your code and failed to supply an object reference. You cannot use the class name itself to qualify a member that is not shared. The instance must first be declared as an object variable and then referenced by the variable name.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwwhc0d0.aspx)

Here is what you can try:

```
   Dim b = New BrandListing()
    b.Show()
```